# How to check if function dosen't do anything?

Tags: c++

I have a class for handling the messages from window:

```
class EventHandler
{
private:
  std::vector<EventReciver*> recievers;

public:
  EventHandler(GLFWwindow* window);
  inline void add_reciever(EventReciver* rec) { recievers.push_back(rec); };

  void resize_callback(int width, int height)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < recievers.size(); i++)
    {
        recievers[i]->resize_callback(width,height);
    };
};

void key_callback(int key, int scancode, int action, int mode)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < recievers.size(); i++)
  {
    recievers[i]->key_callback(key, scancode,action,mode);
  };
};

  ~EventHandler();
};
```

If i want to reccive messages with my custom classes my class should inherit from EventReciever:

```
class EventReciver
{
public: 
  inline EventReciver() {};
private:
  
  void virtual resize_callback(int width, int height) {};
  void virtual key_callback(int key, int scancode, int action, int mode) {};
  friend class EventHandler;
};
```

Also i want to implement only callbacks,which class need, for example:

```
class A : public EventReciver
{
public:
private:
  void resize_callback(int width, int height) override { /*do some stuff*/ };
};
class B : public EventReciver
{
public:
private:
  void key_callback(int width, int height) override { /*do some stuff*/ };
};
```

But with this implementation empy functions,which were not overriden, also called.How to call only functions,which actually do something?

Comment: What benefit to you think you'll achieve by not calling the empty base class implementation of the virtual functions?

Comment: *How to call only functions,which actually do something?* -- If the functions don't do anything, then the compiler's optimizer would probably optimize the function away.  There is no need to micromanage this yourself.  Anyway, how would you have determined that `{ int x = 0; }` doesn't do anything?  A variable is declared and set to 0, but nothing else.  You see how far the "doesn't do anything" rabbit-hole you can get yourself into?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm -- a GUI interface has over a gajillion possible callback functions. I wouldn't want to develop or maintain a base class with that many virtual functions. The technique we used in Borland's Object Windows Library (OWL) was for each event handler class to have a static map of event codes to member functions.

Comment: @PeteBecker cant you tell more about this, please? Where in the source code can i find it?

Comment: You might split your `EventReceiver` with one for `resize_callback` and one for `key_callback` and split accordingly your `std::vector<EventReceiver*> receivers;`